# Object doesn't support property or method 'selectbox'

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, drop-down-menu

I'm using the selectbox jQuery plugin from http://www.bulgaria-web-developers.com/projects/javascript/selectbox/ .

I also have a linked in js file, which contains the following code:

```
function loadTeams() {
var responseArray, optionsOutput = '';

$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "/ajax/team",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (response) {
        responseArray = response.array;

        for (var i = 0; i < responseArray.length; i++) {
            optionsOutput += '<option value="' + responseArray[i] + '">' + responseArray[i] + '</option>';
        }

        $("#teamSelect").find('option')
                        .remove()
                        .end()
                        .append(optionsOutput);
        $("#teamSelect").selectbox({ speed: 100 });  
    },
    error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
        $("#teamSelect").find('option')
        .remove()
        .end()
        .append('<option value=""></option>');
    }
});
```

}

This works fine in all browsers except IE.  In there, I get:

> SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'selectbox' 
>   globals.js, line 38 character 4

That equates to the following line:

```
$("#teamSelect").selectbox({ speed: 100 });
```

I've tried even such dramatic and ugly approaches as copying the entire jQuery plugin js file into `globals.js`, and I still get the error.

What gives?

Edit - Update:  I've tried assigning the `#teamSelect` to a `var` and calling `var.selectbox`, but I'm getting the same error.

Comment: This works fine in all browsers except IE => this is really shocking! :D see my avatar, i recommend you use my avatar on website if you can :D

Comment: Can you confirm that  $("#teamSelect") is defined before you call selectbox? Are there any other error messages shown in the console at this point?

Comment: There's no other errors in the IE console and the teamSelect selectbox is part of the static HTML.  The jQuery selectbox plugin is defined after jQuery and before loadTeams.  loadTeams fires onload.

Comment: Are you happen to test it using localhost URL? If so, try to use your computer name instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aha, the problem was a conflict between jQuery's selectbox plugin (probably jQuery itself) and Foundation 4.  When I integrated Foundation 4, I followed the example on their site which had me copy and paste in this cryptic bit:

```
<script>
    document.write('<script src=' +
    ('__proto__' in {} ? '/js/vendor/zepto' : '/js/vendor/jquery') +
    '.js><\/script>');
</script>
```

This was loading zepto or jquery, and THEN I was loading jquery from the Google CDN.  Removing this line and placing my Google CDN of jQuery first resolved the conflict.